# How do I set the step size for dnorm in R when calculating the normal distribution of a sequence?

Tags: r, statistics

I am new to R, and I am trying to generate y=Normal(x) for -5 ≤ x ≤ 5, step size = 0.1, and then sum the y-values. But I am having trouble figuring out how to set the step size to 0.1. I know that for a normal distribution the mean is 0 and the sd is 1. How can I set the step size? Does it have to do with the length? Thank you,

````
y <- dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1)
sum(y)```

Returns: 3.989423
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like below?

```
x <- seq(-5,5,by = 0.1)
y <- dnorm(x)
```

I guess you attempt to calculate the integral of normal distribution over interval -5 to 5, so here are some approaches

```
> sum(y)*0.1 #(not recommended) this method achieves relatively precise integral only if you have fine steps
[1] 0.9999996
```

or

```
> integrate(dnorm,-5,5)
0.9999994 with absolute error < 8.7e-10
```

or

```
> pnorm(5)-pnorm(-5)
[1] 0.9999994
```